# Why does using $this inside a class in a Wordpress plugin throw a fatal error?

Tags: php, class, wordpress

I'm in the process of writing a Wordpress plugin which creates a page in the admin area, as well as executing some frontend code.

The code below throws a nice `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` error. Which is rather mystifying, as the variable is called inside the class.

Maybe I'm not following the intended Wordpress plugin structure for functions and classes, but the conceptual code below was created using the relevant entries on plugin development in the Wordpress Codex.

Could somebody explain why the error is triggered, because when I create an instance of the class outside of the Wordpress codebase everything is fine.

```
if (!class_exists("MyClass")) {
  class MyClass {
    var $test = 'Test variable';

    public function index() {
      //Index code
    }

    public function add() {
      echo $this->test;
    }
  }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

function my_plugin_menu() {
  add_menu_page('My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin', array('MyClass', 'index'));
  add_submenu_page('my-plugin', 'Add New Thing', 'Add New', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-add', array('MyClass', 'add'));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I've seem to have fixed it, by going back to the basics and asking Google the humble question: *"Using classes in Wordpress plugins".*

Both the article by [Jay Fortner](http://w3prodigy.com/behind-wordpress/php-classes-wordpress-plugin/) and one on [dConstructing.com](http://www.dconstructing.com/php/2011/01/08/using-classes-to-develop-wordpress-plugins/) were helpful.

Basically, I'm now calling add_menu_page and add_submenu_page from within the class. I was under the impression those functions somehow created an object, but they obviously don't.

My code now looks something like this and I'm able to call the declared class variable without error:

```
if (!class_exists("MyClass")) {
  class MyClass {
    var $test = 'Test variable';

    function __construct() {
      add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');
    }

    function my_plugin_menu() {
      add_menu_page('My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin', array(&$this, 'index'));
      add_submenu_page('my-plugin', 'Add New Thing', 'Add New', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-add', array(&$this, 'add'));
    }

    public function index() {
      //Index code
    }

    public function add() {
      echo $this->test;
    }
  }
  new MyClass;
}
```

Comment: Hey..., the code is not working for me. So, I change this `add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');` function to this `add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'my_plugin_menu'));`

Answer (score 5):

This is no longer true.

> Don't forget, if you pass in the class, you may want to pass it by
>   reference, you can even pass a classes own functions using &$this
>   inside of a class and continue to modify the same instance, this helps
>   to not have to recreate  a class everytime you call a different part
>   of the plugin but the same class.

From: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array

> As of PHP 5.4, the array is no longer passed by reference despite the
>   function's name. You cannot even use the reference sign '&' because
>   call time pass by reference now throws an error. What you can do is
>   pass the reference pointer as an array element. Doing so does require
>   all callbacks added to the action to expect a reference pointer. This
>   is not something you will see in WordPress actions. This technique is
>   provided for informational purposes only.

```
$Class = new MyClass();
 add_menu_page(
       'My Plugin',
        'My Plugin',
        'manage_options',
        'my-plugin',
        array(&$Class, 'index')
```

Or

```
$myClass= new MyClass ;

add_action('admin_menu', array( $myClass, 'admin_menu' ) );

class MyClass 
{
    public function admin_menu()
    {   
        add_menu_page('MyMenu', 'MyMenu', 'read', 'mymenu', array( $this, 'action' ));  
    }
    public function action()
    {   
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside action i added form tag. So what should i pass in action and where can i get post value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the $_POST array for post values.

Answer (score 4):

What you should do is the following:

```
function my_plugin_menu()
{
add_menu_page('My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin', array(new MyClass, 'index'));
add_submenu_page('my-plugin', 'Add New Thing', 'Add New', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-add', array('MyClass', 'add'));
}
```

Using `array('MyClass', 'index')` cause php to execute the method as a  static methed, but passing an actual object as the first argument will call the method via the object.

```
function my_plugin_menu()
{
    $Class = new MyClass();
    add_menu_page(
        'My Plugin',
        'My Plugin',
        'manage_options',
        'my-plugin',
        array($Class, 'index')
    );
}
```

Would also work if you want to reuse the object.

Answer (score 1):

depends how the class is being called, statically Class::method() will throw errors. If that is the case i think you need to use self::$test; but could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure how Wordpress calls the class, but using self::test instead of $this->test doesn't resolve the error, I'm afraid.